# How to prototype with PHP and HTML5 forms when I cannot view the result?

Tags: php, html

I recently started PHP (I am a beginner) and I wanted to create a form with HTML to add numbers together. However, when I send queries to PHP  it shows my source code (because it is not a server - file is run locally). I was wondering would it be possible to preview my PHP's code result on a website of some sort or even better on my computer? Do you know any services or ways to accomplish this, preferably free of charge?

Answer (score 0):

To run php files online, go to [Write Code Online](http://writecodeonline.com/php).

As long as you can install programs on your computer, you should install a web server to run php files locally.  To run any basic app, especially if it uses forms, you will use multiple php files and the testing will be too complex to run online.  If you are using windows, install [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).  For mac, try [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/).

Answer (score 0):

you seriously require some help :-)

First, PHP is a server side scripting language, so it requires server (like Apache, which you can install using the wamp or xampp installers) Try to search google on how to install them on local computer.

Second, their are some online PHP editors, like http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php or writecodeonline .com and many others. It may not replace the server but helps to write the PHP code and execute it for the sake of practising.

Also, it is better if you read some tutorials about PHP. One tutorial I can point you to is the http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp which is related to question.